# what is wrong with my pokemon go app?

Tags: pokemon-go

My brother and I downloaded pokemon go together a couple days ago. I had to delete some apps because I barely had any storage on my Samsung galaxy s5. We went out to find some pokemon this morning for about 30 mins. He found a bunch of pokemon but they were not showing up on my phone. I ran out of data but I'm on a plan that if you run out, it just gets slower instead of being charged extra. I don't know if that is the reason. Can someone help me out because I really want to play this game but no pokemon are showing up no matter where I go.

Answer (score 0):

The servers may be experiencing issues right now. Your best bet is to try again later.